# Why did multicellular organisms evolve when a single cell can survive on its own?

Tags: evolution, cell-biology

Since unicellular organisms can survive, why would there be evolution of multicellular organisms?

Comment: Potential duplicate of [*Why would a single celled organism evolve to be multi-celled?*](http://biology.stackexchange.com/q/13595/3624)