# Difference in multicellularity between prokaryotic and eukaryotic organisms

Tags: evolution, eukaryotic-cells, prokaryotic-cells

As most prokaryotic organisms are single-celled, and in eukaryotic organisms this is the reverse, is there some evolutionary advantage that led to these features evolving? Or is it purely the fact that features of eukaryotic cells allow functions (i.e. enabling multicellular organisms) not possible in prokaryotic cells?

Comment: What matters is how many times multicellularity evolve and not so much how many species are multicellular. Have a look at [this answer](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/13595/why-would-a-single-celled-organism-evolve-to-be-multi-celled/21525#21525) section `How many times did multicellularity evolve independently?`

Comment: Your title question does not match with you content question. Are you interested in the evolution of size or of multicellularity?

Comment: Multicellularity - apologies, I thought the terms were almost synonymous